# Simple one to many relation (association) fails in EF designer

Tags: entity-framework-4, associations

I tried setting up a simple one-to-many relation in Entity Frameworks designer.

The tables are **Category (1)** and **Transaction (N).** Here's what I did:

```
Add "association"

 End1 = Category, multiplicity 1, navigation property=Transaction
 End2 = Transaction, multiplicity Many, navigation property = Category
```

Building it gave me the error "No mapping specified". Ok, makes sense. So I added this mapping:

```
 Category
   Category.CategoryID = Transaction.CategoryID
```

But the mapping designer also automatically adds a mapping for the Transaction table, which I cannot figure out how to delete or how to setup:

```
 Transaction
    Transaction.TransactionID = ???
```

Leaving it empty seems most valid, but that gives me: Error 3024 "Must specify mapping for all key properties (TransactionID)"

And trying to set it to a fake int property just hoping it's a compiler bug. But that gives me errors 3002 and 3003.

I dont get what to do. Isnt Associations meant to be used this way?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating (or importing from the database) an entity for Catagory and an entity for Transaction. Add scalar properties to each as needed. Next, right-click on your entity, click Table Mapping, and map your entity properties to the table fields. For example, for the Category entity, map CategoryID field to a CategoryID property. Do the same for the other entity. THEN create the association.

Note that associations linked by exposed foreign keys do not have any mappings. 
BTW, you'll probably want to add navigation properties as well.